# how website check that a upload stuff is images or not

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

how website check the file uploaded by user is image or not. i want to do this in asp.net mvc c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass the file contents into a Bitmap object (using the ctor with Stream parameter), and if the constructor throws an ArgumentException, it's not an image (for popular image formats, mind you).